# PG Sql query profiling

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-performance

How can I check how much time my Select query is taking to read record.
I am using Postgres and SQL Workbench as editor.

I tried **pg_stat_activity** but it didn't give me result for my query.

Comment: An example of what query are you using and what you expect?, I'm using pg_stat_activity too and it's working fine

Comment: I am using select * from pg_stat_activity; it is giving me result but not for my query. Query column has all other statements including COMMIT and ROLLBACK but not mine.

Comment: `explain (analyze) select ...`

Comment: Result of query with explain.

Planning time: 0.728 ms
Execution time: 20.578 ms 

Execution time is the time taken by query we can consider?